# Pythonic way to select characters after specific character sequence in string

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings like

```
lst = ['foo000bar111', 'foo000bar1112', 'foo000bar1113']
```

and I want to extract the last numbers from each string to get

```
nums = ['111', '1112', '1113']
```

I have other numbers earlier in the string that I don't care about (`000` in this example). There aren't spaces, so I can't `lst.split()` and I believe doing something like that without spacing is difficult. The numbers are of different lengths, so I can't just do `str[-3:]`. For what it's worth, the characters before the numbers I care about are the same in each string, and the numbers are at the end of the string.

I'm looking for a way to say 'ok, read until you find `bar` and then tell me what's the rest of the string.' The best I've come up with is `[str[(str.index('bar')+3):] for str in lst]`, which works, but I doubt that's the most pythonic way to do it.

Comment: You are already doing it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is accurate. You can also try using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['foo000bar111', 'foo000bar1112', 'foo000bar1113']
>>> [re.search(r'(\d+$)',i).group() for i in lst]
['111', '1112', '1113']
```

You can also try `rindex`

```
>>> [i[i.rindex('r')+1:] for i in lst]
['111', '1112', '1113']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your own solution works well enough, but I think the main problem with is that you have to hard-code the length of the search string you are using. This could be solved using a temporary variable like this:

```
tag = 'bar'
[s[(s.index(tag)+len(tag)):] for s in lst]
```

One alternative way using [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
[x.rsplit('bar', 1)[1] for x in lst]
```

This always splits on the last occurrence of `bar`, even if it occurs more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I actually had to do a little extra because I needed to remove a file extension, and rsplit worked great.

Comment: This is really great idea and you get my vote for it. However please change the variable from `str` to something else in the first list comp as `str` is a built in variable name. :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks, fixed. I copied that code from the question without looking too much, I try not to do that in my own code ...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not bad at all, but you could improve it in a couple of ways:

1. Use `rindex()` instead of index; if `bar` should happen to occur twice (or more) in a string, you want to find the last instance.
2. Or you can use `rsplit()`:

   ```
   [ s.rsplit("bar", 1)[1] for s in lst ]
   ```

**Edit:** @Bas beat me to the second solution by a few seconds! :-)